# JQuery, a litle help to understand what this function fo with JSON

Tags: json, jquery, http-headers

I am studing the Spring MVC Showcase that use JQuery but I'm pretty new to JQuery world

I have some doubt about the behavior of a JQuery function founded studing this example.

So, I have the following link that generate an HTTP Request towards the "/mapping/produces" folder

```
        <li>
            <a id="byProducesAcceptJson" class="writeJsonLink" href="<c:url value="/mapping/produces" />">By produces via Accept=application/json</a>
        </li>
```

As you can see this link have class named "writeJsonLink" and for this class there is defined the following JQuery function triggered on the click of the link:

```
$("a.writeJsonLink").click(function() {
    var link = $(this); // Variable that contain the referer to the clicked link 

    // Execute ajax call
    $.ajax({ url: this.href,    

        // Before send the request to the server execute the following function
        beforeSend: function(req) {
            if (!this.url.match(/\.json$/)) {
                req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            }
        },
        success: function(json) {
            MvcUtil.showSuccessResponse(JSON.stringify(json), link);
        },
        error: function(xhr) {
            MvcUtil.showErrorResponse(xhr.responseText, link);
        }});
    return false;
});
```

My problem is that I have some problem to understand the meaning of the if condition, what mean this part of code?

```
            if (!this.url.match(/\.json$/)) {
                req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            }
```

seeing how it seems to me that only adds a header to the HTTP Request...but I think that actually do something with JSON...I have also some problem to unbderstand the meaning of the if logic condition...

Thank you very much
Andrea

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell, the code checks if the endpoint URL ends with `.json`, if so then it adds a `Accept: application/json` header.

```
        if (!this.url.match(/\.json$/)) {
            req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        }
```

#### this.url

Get the URL from the current xHR Object

#### [match](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp)

The match() method searches a string for a match against a regular expression, and returns the matches, as an Array object.

#### /.json$/

Is a simple regular expression that check if the URL is ending with `.json`

#### req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");

Req is again the extended xHR object and  [setRequestHeader()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Setting_HTTP_request_headers) is used to set headers for a request. 
Sets the accplication/json in the Accept header of the request. something like `Accept: application/json`